# CRM 2013 Default Credentials Login returns System User/Integration User

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, windows-authentication, credentials, application-pool

i have create A web service. Web service has been deployed on Machine1 and CRM is on Machine 2.

The user can login to both the machines. In My Web service i read the connection string using below credentials and create letter. I assume it takes default credentials for login.

I have provided only connectionstring in my web.config and no user and password has been provided.

```
    <add name="Connection" connectionString="Url=https://CRmURL/; " />
```

When i create letter the user is being set to System User and on my dev it is being set to Integration user.

How can we set current logged-in user?

**I am calling Web Service through VBA macro code.**

/// Here URLCRM is WEb Service URL

xmlHttp.Open "POST", URLCRM, False
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                  'Send new Document to CRM Service.
                 sendStr = "idContact=" & lGuid & "&templateName=" & templateName _
                     & "&xmlWordContent=" & HTMLEncode1(workingDocument.Range.XML) _
                     & "&subject=" & HTMLEncode1(subject) _
                     & "&close=" & IIf(isclose, "true", "false")
                 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(sendStr)
                 xmlHttp.send sendStr

Thanks!

Comment: Please share you application pool settings. Check the Application pool used for Web service and try to set `Load user profile` to `true`.

Comment: Are you capturing the current user details when a request is coming to Web service.

Comment: I am calling Web Service through VBA macro code.I have updated question. In My web service I use connectionstring configured in web service web.config.

Comment: Problem is the app pool identity is set to Integration user..

Comment: Is it working for you now? have you set the `Load user profile` to true

Comment: No it is still not working... I have changed Web service authentication to windows. In such a case it shows the prompt for credentials and creates the record for user that is provided in prompt window. .. It should take default credentials... Why can't it take default credentials of logged in user on machine?

Comment: It looks like an authentication issue. So I will suggest you to update your post or create a new one with appropriate tags. However, I am adding new tags to your post to attract exerts of authentication.